# How to store integers sepated by commas in a variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to store randomly generated integers in a single variable. They need to be separated by commas such that I can put the variable into a function and it will accept the syntax.

```
from SimpleGraphics import *

import random

pieColourR = random.randint(0, 255)
pieColourG = random.randint(0, 255)
pieColourB = random.randint(0, 255)

colourA = (pieColourR, pieColourG, pieColourB)

setFill(colourA)
rect(200, 100, 400, 400)
```

The three RGB values need to be accepted by the "setFill" function. I am doing this to randomly generate 3 different colours that will be consistent for the entire run time of the program.

Right now I get this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "166 134 15"
```

Comment: try if `setFill` takes 3 numbers:  `setFill(*colourA)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ukemi has answered your question correctly.  You do not want to pass three arguments into the `setFill()` function, you want to pass a single argument with a known name or, alternatively, a pseudo-name created using the method ukemi described.

However, there *are* cases in which you want to convert a tuple or list into separate arguments to pass into a function. This can be done with Python's unpacking syntax:

```
someFunction(*colorA)
```

Comment: Thanks! Turns out the function I was using accepted my input when I used the unpacking syntax, but not if I used ukemi's solution.

Comment: someFunc(*args) is also called as a function which accepts the arbitrary parameter, which later can be used as list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the argument to `setFill` in an expected format. An acceptable one is thus:

```
colourA = color_rgb(pieColourR, pieColourG, pieColourB)
setFill(colourA)
```

See here for more info:

http://anh.cs.luc.edu/handsonPythonTutorial/graphics.html#random-colors